# Failed to start User Manager, No CGroup Medium Found

Tags: ubuntu, boot, systemd, cgroup

I have run into a strange issue that, from what I can tell, the root cause is associated with or directly related to CGroups.  Unfortunately I do not understand enough about SystemD or CGroups to know how to troubleshoot and diagnose the root cause accurately.  What I *do* know is that virtually any user SystemD service (i.e. `systemctl --user start xyz`) fails to start and the error messages are fairly consistent:

```
user@1000.service: Failed to enable/disable controllers on cgroup /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service, ignoring: Permission denied
user@1000.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=219/CGROUP
```

This is on Ubuntu 22.04 and I've tried the following Kernel versions so far:

- v6.5.0-17-generic
- v6.5.0-15-generic

`systemctl --failed`:

```
  UNIT                        LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                                                     
● apcupsd.service             loaded failed failed UPS power management daemon
● apply-cgroups.service       loaded failed failed Apply CGroup settings
● dnsmasq.service             loaded failed failed dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
● grub-common.service         loaded failed failed Record successful boot for GRUB
● kerneloops.service          loaded failed failed Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures
● nvidia-persistenced.service loaded failed failed NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
● rpc-statd.service           loaded failed failed NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking.
● user@1000.service           loaded failed failed User Manager for UID 1000
● user@1004.service           loaded failed failed User Manager for UID 1004
● user@130.service            loaded failed failed User Manager for UID 130
● vmware-tools.service        loaded failed failed VMWare Tools Service
```

The `apply-cgroups.service` is something I wrote, here are the contents (I have disabled this service, rebooted, but that doesn't seem to change anything):

```
[Unit]
Description=Apply CGroup settings

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=cgcreate -g cpu,cpuacct:/foo-app
ExecStart=cgset -r cpu.cfs_quota_us=750000 /foo-app
ExecStart=cgset -r memory.limit_in_bytes=8G /foo-app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Contents of `/sys/fs/cgroup`, and my research tells me that this indicates CGroups v2 is not available:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Feb 14 01:17 cgroup.clone_children
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Feb 14 01:17 cgroup.procs
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Feb 14 01:17 cgroup.sane_behavior
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Feb 14 01:20 dev-hugepages.mount
--w-------  1 root root 0 Feb 14 01:17 devices.allow
--w-------  1 root root 0 Feb 14 01:17 devices.deny
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Feb 14 01:17 devices.list
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Feb 14 01:20 dev-mqueue.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Feb 14 01:17 notify_on_release
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Feb 14 01:20 proc-fs-nfsd.mount
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Feb 14 01:20 proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Feb 14 01:17 release_agent
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Feb 14 01:20 sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Feb 14 01:20 sys-kernel-config.mount
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Feb 14 01:20 sys-kernel-debug.mount
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Feb 14 01:20 sys-kernel-tracing.mount
drwxr-xr-x 99 root root 0 Feb 14 01:45 system.slice
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Feb 14 01:17 tasks
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 0 Feb 14 01:29 user.slice
```

`cat /proc/filesystems` reveals that both `cgroup` and `cgroup2` are available:

```
...
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cgroup2
...
```

During the re-installation of packages as a troubleshooting step, I have seen this error message periodically, and I'm afraid I don't even understand what this service is or what it's trying to achieve:

```
Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

And finally, I found this from some troubleshooting advice that may provide some clues:

```
02:32:20 > systemd --user
Cannot determine cgroup we are running in: No medium found
Failed to allocate manager object: No medium found
```

What does this mean and what sort of medium is it looking for?  My key trouble here is that I don't really know the tools well enough to diagnose the root cause of this, so I have been spitballing fruitlessly, and that's why I'm reaching out to SO for answers.